# Big file upload give HTTP error

Tags: uploads, media

Just, when I go to `Add New` *(/wp-admin/media-new.php)* in `Media` menu, when I choose a big file, about 30 mb, upload progress bar stuck on `100%` and give me an error in console:

> load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,plupload-handlers&ver=4.7.14:40
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

I just installed wordperss, and no plugin installed, 5.2.3 version

Also via *(wp-admin/upload.php)* when I upload via pressing `add new` button it give me error:

> HTTP error.

In console:

> async-upload.php:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with
>   a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1):

That issue is not due to WordPress but due to your server configuration. Try increasing the PHP memory on the server as well as the max upload filesize.

If you do not know how to do that please contact your hosting provider. Each server is different for that configuration therefore you won't be able to get a specific answer.

Comment: Memory limit is 128 mb and max upload size is also 128, file is 30 mb!

Comment: Whenever you see a 500 error it is as if you saw the wording "error" without any details. The 500 error is a generic server error which can mean anything. For that reason please contact your hosting provider to solve this issue.